# java.util.zip.ZipException on Retrofit and GSON

Tags: java, android

Hi i am getting this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class

When I added the retrofit GSON converter to my gradle here is my gradle.

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  compile files('libs/GenAsync.1.2.jar')
  compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
  compile files('libs/KGJsonConverter.jar')
  compile files('libs/MD5Simply.jar')
  compile files('libs/PhotoUtil.jar')
  compile files('libs/android-viewbadger.jar')
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile files('libs/retrofit-2.1.0.jar')
}
```

Can you help me guys with my problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class `com.google.gson.annotations.Expose` is defined in more than one dependency. You need to exclude or remove conflicting dependencies.

Eg. `com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0` already contains transitive dependency `com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7` so there is no need to declare also `compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')`.